# Review idea, Adding a notification for reviews

Tags: feature-request, review

So I've been trying to do my civic duty by reviewing posts.  Right now it pretty much goes like this, open the page to review, find "no items to review", then occasionally refresh during the day, most of the time getting "no items to review". At the end I might be lucky enough to review a couple of items per day.

I think a good idea would be the following.

- You go to the review page, click a "I'd like to review" button, then wait. Clicking the button adds you to a queue of people who will review items.  While waiting you could leave this tab open and continue using StackExchange.
- When it's your turn to review a polite notification would occur (I think most browsers support some notification now, or you can just use the StackExchange red "!")
- Once the notificiation appears you now have x seconds to press a button that says I'm now reviewing this item.
- If you handle the item great, if not then it gets reviewed by someone else.
- If a person doesn't review they are also automatically removed from reviewers queue and must click the "I'm ready to review" button again to be eligible for more items.

Since the queue is pretty much empty all the time you can also just send the same item to multiple people, which has been suggested as a benefit before anyway, which would make sure the item gets handled promptly even if multiple people are afk.

The primary benefit to this system is mainly that it allows users to do other things while waiting to contribute. But, by making it a friendlier system I think you would find more people would want to contribute (which would allow you to send items to multiple reviewers for extra checking), and it might even help reduce server load by less refresh spamming on the review pages.

Comment: Is it too much to ask for e-mail notifications? Or is that causing too much load on the page? Because I'm not on SE 24/7, I check it every hour or so, but most of the time I've missed some reviews (especially in LQ Posts, or Suggested Edits), so it would be nice to get a notification that a new post was avaliable for review

Answer (score 7):

I think this idea is generally a good concept, but the implementation should be different.  Rather than expecting people to sit on the review page waiting for a popup, how about we stick with the general look&feel of SO, and put a little red bubble over Review when there are items to review?  That could be optional (on the Review page, somewhere leave a checkbox for "I'd like to be notified about new Review items" just like the original suggestion; or on the profile, or both).

Then when there is something other than close request to review [there are always close requests, so those need to be excluded] you get a red bubble over Review, and can click on it if you're interested in doing reviews then.  That way you don't have to sit on the review page, but instead can do useful things like post answers, and still do reviews when they are available.

Comment: I updated the idea, I think its clearer now

Comment: When I came across this answer, I was about to post a feature request for just this. I've realized, though, that unless the page were reloaded constantly, this badge would always (frustratingly) be out of date.

Comment: @rogaos This would be no different from the badge in the upper left telling you about updates to posts and such.  That updates without a page refresh.  And even if it did, it's not like most of us just sit on a page without doing anything...