# How to get notified when new posts are added in review Queues

Tags: feature-request, support

It's been a while that I am allowed to review first posts & Late answer Review Queues. The issue is, every time I open review queue, it shows 0. Sometimes it shows other numbers too, but before I'm able to see the post, it would no longer be available for me.

I've seen many users reviewing all the queues very frequently. So just have a doubt. Is there any method to get notified when new posts are added in the queues??

Or may be, if its not there, there should be a feature of similar kind I think ..

Comment: just keep hitting reload...

Comment: There is a script that runs every 5 minutes adding tasks to the queue so you have to dive in at that moment, if no items are left wait 5 minutes and try again...

Comment: I give up searching for an authoritive link to my claim. There will be light when a dev passes by...

Comment: As far as a feature request, this might cover similar territory: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180868/review-idea-adding-a-notification-for-reviews

Comment: People got tools that keep auto refreshing every second or so until there is review item, saw someone mention it somewhere. Nothing official, user script or browser add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally @rene's comment works good for me..

There is a script that runs every 5 minutes adding tasks to the queue so you have to dive in at that moment, if no items are left wait 5 minutes and try again...